# Django Datefield attributes

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

i have Datefield in my model where it should save when created and updated what should be the attributes inside?

**models.py**

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    edited = models.DateField(*what should be the attributes here*)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add two attributes, One is **created_at** and another is **edited_at**

```
created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
edited_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

auto_now -> Automatically set the field to now every time the object is saved.

auto_now_add -> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created.

for details [see the reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)

Comment: Brother i clearly mentioned that i should and will have only one field edited and it should be updated when it is created or updated

Comment: @mikan Then simply use `auto_now`. This will work for every saving of the object.

Comment: @dgw yes i got to know this thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#datefield).

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    edited = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

`auto_now_add` attribute's `True` value will add current date whenever you create that object for `MyModel`

and then let's see an example:

in your `views.py`

```
data = MyModel.objects.get(id=some_id) 
data.some_field1 = 'some-value' 
data.some_field2 = 'some-value' 
data.edited = datetime.date.today() 
data.save()
```

You have to just do this

Comment: will this update when i change something

Comment: This will update one time when you create an object, but after that whenever you update that data, if you want to update this field's value you have do this manually in your view.

Comment: I have added an example with my solution, please have a look on that.

Answer (score 0):

We can use custom save method as auto_now or auto_now_add will not show in admin panel.
Below is the example for the same
By this approach we can actually track both when  it is created and when it is updated.

```
from django.utils import timezone

class User(models.Model):
    created     = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    edited    = models.DateTimeField()
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        self.edited = timezone.now()
    return super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer brother but here we only have one field displayed on FE that is edited we should have only one field showing data whether its created or updated.